# AngularJS call scope function on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-route in in my angular app. As soon as the url changes I don't want to update the templateUrl or controller, but I want to call a function in scope with route param. How to do it?

Should I provide same controller and call the function in controller itself? This is assuming that the controller's constructor is called again on route change.
I haven't tried it as there might be a better way to do it? I am new to angular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this in your controller :

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 8):

angular-route.js broadcast events `$routeUpdate`, `$routeChangeStart`, `$routeChangeSuccess` on `$rootScope`, so you can listen to one of them

add this to your scope on which you want to detect route change

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (next, last) {
   $scope.someFunction();
});
```

Comment: I previously had '$stateChangeStart' and after changing to 'routeChangeStart' it worked! thank you!